# Alamofire: ParameterEncoding: Send empty array as parameter body for PUT operation

Tags: arrays, swift3, alamofire

I have to send an empty array in the parameter body for PUT operation. Internally `ParameterEncoding` class is called and while constructing the request a method called `queryComponents(fromKey key: String, value: Any?) -> [(String, String)]` is called. This method appends every component in the request. If the array is empty, then the parameter itself is ignored through this code:

```
if let array = value as? [Any] {
for value in array {
                components += queryComponents(fromKey: "\(key)[]", value: value)
            }
        }
```

But I want my request to also send the empty array. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context in how you're using this? It's hard to advise you how to build this if we don't know how you're using it.

Comment: By the way, this smells like `POST`, not `PUT`: "The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource. "